# Running jQuery with dynamic content when I need the size

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, flot

I've got a page in my web app that dynamically loads a view containing html and some javascript. The javascript basically renders a chart into the view that's been retrieved. The issue is that the chart library I'm using (flot) requires that the container it is being rendered into has a width and height.

When the javascript is being executed, the CSS rules haven't been applied to the container and it doesn't have a size. How can I wait until the CSS has been applied before the javascript runs?

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, you can do

```
    $(window).load(function()
    {
      //code fires after the layout has been calculated/rendered
    });
```

The doesn't work if you have javascript changing CSS after the page has already been loaded tho...so be sure any JS changing CSS happens before anything else you're about to do

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was simply being a complete idiot!
I was passing the container ID to flot without the "#" so it wasn't finding a container at all. The CSS rules have been applied when the view is returned and it's now working fine :)